# How to select bracketed columns from a table with a variable

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, delimiter

I have a simple table that has the following columns. I want to create a WHILE loop that will return each column like so. How can I do this?

```
create table #bracket_example (row_num int identity(0,1), [0] int, [1] int, [2] int, [3] int)
insert #bracket_example values (25,35,45,55)
insert #bracket_example values (32,53,98,67)
insert #bracket_example values (33,44,55,66)
insert #bracket_example values (11,14,15,16)
declare @j int
set @j = 0

while @j < 4
begin
select '[' + cast(@j as varchar(2)) + ']' from #bracket_example
set @j = @j + 1
end
```

so instead of listing the values, it's just listing the column names.  How can I get this to list values instead?

Comment: it's always good to add the expected result in your question. you question is not very clear. what are you trying to get from your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #bracket_example (row_num int identity(0,1), [0] int, [1] int, [2] int, [3] int)

insert #bracket_example values (25,35,45,55)
insert #bracket_example values (32,53,98,67)
insert #bracket_example values (33,44,55,66)
insert #bracket_example values (11,14,15,16)

declare @j int
declare @DynSQL varchar(50)
set @j = 0

while @j < 4
begin

set @DynSQL = 'select [' + cast(@j as varchar(2)) + '] as Column_' + cast(@j as varchar(10)) + ' from #bracket_example'

EXEC (@DynSQL)

set @j = @j + 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your solutions.  As it turns out, I need to have a WHERE statement to filter out some of the data from #bracket_example, so I'm just going to hard-code this section.  I already know the exact rows I need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to use DynamicSql. Please try this :

```
while @j < 4
begin
EXEC sp_executesql 'select [' + cast(@j as varchar(2)) + '] from #bracket_example'
set @j = @j + 1
end
```